# IPv6 support for Help Contents in RCP application

Tags: java, jetty, eclipse-rcp, rcp, embedded-jetty

In my RCP application, I am using Eclipse's Help System. When connected to the IPv4 interface, the help window opens up as expected. But, as soon as I switch to the IPv6 only interface, after clicking Help -> Help Contents, the window doesn't open up.

Please find the attached pic for reference.[RCP application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pKVo.png)

Also, I tried digging into the root cause and came across this file "JettyHelpServer.java" present inside the **org.eclipse.help.base/src/org/eclipse/help/internal/server/JettyHelpServer.java**, and found that the IPv4 is hardcoded.

Is it because of this?
[JettyHelpServer.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JIi6.png)

Any help would be really appreciated as to how I can add support for IPv6 only.

Comment: Did you try running you application with `-Dserver_host=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`?

Comment: @howlger - Yes, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried running it with -Dserver_host=localhost, and now it is working for both IPv4 and IPv6 flawlessly. Maybe because localhost gets resolved to both the v4 and v6 addresses. Anyway, your comment/idea of passing it as an argument helped. Thanks a lot, @howlger!

Comment: Great! Please add a self-answer to help others.